# Export Blender edges/lines into Unreal or other game engines

Tags: mesh, modifiers, export, edges, wireframe

These lines are basically edges. In Blender:
https://ibb.co/4TnnZRL

Yet in unreal, the lines on the torso and ear does not show up. How do I export these edges/lines in Unreal? Do I use a Blender modifier? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Blender shows edges as 1px lines, while game engines will show only polygons, edges will be skipped because it has no geometry to show.

Blender has an option to export edges as 0-area polygons:

[image]

But it will not help because it should have some width. So in order to render these edges, you should add some depth to it - a polygon or a tube